# R implementation of Tukey's plot for additive two-way tables

Tags: r, plot, anova

In Tukey's *Exploratory Data Aanalysis* book, he presents a novel plot for two-way tables under additivity, i.e., $y_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_j + \beta_j$.

Has this been implemented in R?  A quick Google search turns up nothing. Here is an example, for the `lattice::barley` data, averaged over years.  The arrows show large residuals from the additive model.

[image]

(The plot was done using a SAS macro, http://datavis.ca/sasmac/twoway.html)

Answer (score 2):

No one answered this, so I created an R package `twoway` that now does most of this analysis and plots of this type, available at https://github.com/friendly/twoway

It is not yet available on CRAN. To try it out, install from github via:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("friendly/twoway")
```

Comment: Now available on CRAN

Comment: awesome, thanks for doing this!